# How do I import data using Django-Import-Export?

Tags: django, django-import-export

The documentation for [django-import-export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a bit weak on how to configure the admin to import from a spreadsheet.  Does anyone have a full example?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a fully complete module. But you can understand how it should be.

resources.py file

```
from import_export import resources
from .models import edxUser

class edxUserResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = edxUser
        #skip_unchanged = True
        #report_skipped = True
        #if you want to exclude any field from exporting
        exclude = ('id','edx_anonymized_id') 
        fields = ('id', 'edx_id', 'edx_anonymized_id', 'edx_email', 'edx_name', 'time_created', 'created_by')
        #Order of the export fields
        export_order = ('edx_id', 'edx_email')
```

admin.py file

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import edxUser
from resources import edxUserResource


@admin.register(edxUser)
class edxUserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = edxUserResource
```

models.py file

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class edxUser(models.Model):
    edx_id = models.IntegerField('edX user id', blank=True, null=True)
    edx_anonymized_id = models.IntegerField("edX anonymized user id", blank=True, null=True)
    edx_email = models.EmailField('edx user email', max_length=75, blank=True)
    edx_name = models.CharField('edx name', max_length=75, blank=True, null=True)
    time_created = models.DateField('Created time', blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.edx_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it, assuming that the column names in the spreadsheet are `Title` and `Field one`.  This example assumes that the model instances will be created afresh every import (rather than being updated via a primary key).

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportMixin
from import_export import resources, fields
from .models import MyModel


class MyModelResource(resources.ModelResource):

    title = fields.Field(attribute='title',
                         column_name='Title')
    field_one = fields.Field(attribute='field_one',
                             column_name='Field one')

    def get_instance(self, instance_loader, row):
        # Returning False prevents us from looking in the
        # database for rows that already exist
        return False

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('title', 'field_one')
        export_order = fields


class MyModelAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = MyModelResource


admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Comment: I am updating the rows. But not using the primary key. I have another field with unique=True. How can i give data based on that field ? Now i am getting error 'id' is required.

Comment: it's another question, but for those who will find it: http://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html?highlight=import_id_fields#customize-resource-options